# Integer to double and retain decimal places

Tags: java, formatting, integer, double

How would you convert an `int` to a `double` but still get it to retain two decimal places? 
My code, which prints a double, but I don't know how to round it.

```
System.out.println("Guesses/game = " + ((double) totalguesses / times) / 100);
```

Right now the code will print things like 2.333333333333333 if the answer comes to that and I need it to print 2.33.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can you a [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to format the result:

```
double avgGuesses = ((double) totalguesses / times) / 100;

DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
String avgGuessesFormatted = df.format(avgGuesses);
System.out.println("Guesses/game = " + avgGuessesFormatted);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `String.format()`

```
double yourResult = ...;
String.format("%.2f", yourResult);
```

This prints out `yourResult` with two places after the decimal point.